# PostgreSQL "date at time zone" unexpected behaviour

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

The behavior of the `at time zone` operator on the `date` type is not as expected in PostgreSQL.

```sql
set time zone 'UTC';
select
  '2021-01-03'::date at time zone 'America/Chicago' as "value",
  pg_typeof('2021-01-03'::date at time zone 'America/Chicago') as "type";
```

| x | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Expected** | 2021-01-03 06:00:00+00 | timestamp with time zone |
| **Actual** | 2021-01-02 18:00:00 | timestamp without time zone |

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1377)

Tested on PostgreSQL server versions 10, 11, 12, and 13.

This behavior is very strange to me, and I have not been able to find anywhere it is described or discussed. It seems PSQL is implicitly casting `date` to `timestamptz` (using the system time zone) and then applying the `at time zone` operator. I know that the `at time zone` operator is only defined (in the docs) for the `timestamp(tz)` and `time(tz)` types. However, I would have assumed PSQL would implicitly cast `date` to `timestamp` and not `timestamptz` because:

1. It is a "safe" conversion (no need to assume a time zone). Simply append `00:00:00`.
2. It results in a `timestamptz` which one would expect when using the `at time zone` operator on a type that does not have a time zone.

The current behavior simply doesn't make sense to me and I can't think of a use case that would benefit from it. You are asking for the `timestamp with time zone` for a date at a particular time zone and instead you get a `timestamp` of the date at the system time zone localized to the given time zone.

Of course, a simple workaround is to cast to `timestamp` first:

```sql
set time zone 'UTC';
select '2021-01-03'::date::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago';
```

I was hoping someone could shed some light on this. What am I missing? Perhaps some overarching rule about how `date` is implicitly cast to `timestamp(tz)`? Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Thanks!

- Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask "why". The reason is that `AT TIME ZONE` does not operate on `date`, so PostgreSQL invokes an *implicit type cast* to convert it to a different data type. Lacking an explicit directive, PostgreSQL opts for the *preferred data type* for datetime, which happens to be `timestamp with time zone`.

The data type resolution rules for operators are documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html), and the preferred type for a type category can be found in the `typispreferred` and `typcategory` columns of the [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) system catalog.

Comment: Ah I see! Searching "preferred data type" lead me to [this doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtype.html) on PSQL types which states: "The category and preferred parameters can be used to help control which implicit cast will be applied in ambiguous situations." Which led me to [this doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/typeconv-oper.html) on operator type resolution which explains how implicit conversion is used. `date` is in the date/time `D` category and `timestamptz` is the preferred type in that category. So `timestamptz` is used for the ambiguous implicit conversion.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will add links to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT):
The `AT TIME ZONE` converts `time stamp` without time zone to/from `time stamp` with time zone, and time values to different time zones

Here in first query, you are trying to apply `at time zone` to `date` type, not to `time stamp`

```
set time zone 'UTC';
select
  '2021-01-03'::date at time zone 'America/Chicago' as "value",
  pg_typeof('2021-01-03'::date at time zone 'America/Chicago') as "type";
```

which is eventually gets ignored, and you will get a timestamp without `timezone`

But in second query,

```
set time zone 'UTC';
select '2021-01-03'::date::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago';
```

You are casting the `date` to `time stamp` first and then converting it to desired  `time zone`,
which gives you the expected result of time stamp with time zone.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Right... This is basically what I said. My question was "Why?" Maybe you can expand on this: "which is eventually gets ignored, and you will get a timestamp without timezone". What do you mean by "ignored"? What is ignored? Why is it ignored?